# Adding google_play_services_lib to my android app makes it 5 Mega larger

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, google-play-services

This is something that didn't happen to me in the previous project I did (this is only my second project).

After adding Google Play Services via Properties -> android -> add -> google-play-services_lib the apk size grew by 5 Megabit!

Maybe it's important to mention that I work with eclipse, I tried working with android studio but importing the project was too hard...

Anyway I need this to only present Google ads.

My manifest file looks exactly like this:

```
    <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I have updated the Google Play Services package using the android sdk manager... could this be the reason..?

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: It is bound to increase the size of your apk.The solution for that is to use Proguard and obfuscate the play services library,would decrease apk size to considerable size!

Comment: Shouldn't be possible, the library is quite big but not mega big. Have a look at the apk's content via unzipping the .apk or by using [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) and check where all the megabits went. Maybe you've added the library as a raw asset?

Comment: That's wrong I would say => "I tried working with android studio but importing the project was too hard..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So .. I found the solution in  goonerdroid comment, I started using Proguard and compiling only relevant parts of google play services and the size of my APK decreased significantly.
* the difference is shown only in exported APK but that's what really matters..